# IBDesignable Subclass of TextField renders to IB but not to simulator / device

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uitextfield, custom-controls

I created a subclass of UITextField that adds a floating button to the right hand side of the text-field. It's all good in the IB, but for some reason the button image does not show up in the simulator or on the device.

Using the view debugger,  I can see the button is there, right where it is supposed to be. I can even tap it and get the target action to trigger. However, the image is not visible on the screen.

I tried messing with the clipsToBounds properties of both the TextView and the button to no avail.

I also know the image asset is working, because I made an an image view and set the image to the same image asset, and it appears just fine. The class for the TextField is below:

```
@IBDesignable
class ButtonedTextField: UITextField {

    @IBInspectable var buttonImage: UIImage?
    var button: UIButton?
    var buttonAction: (() -> ())?

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        configure()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        configure()
    }

    @objc private func buttonActionWrap() {
        buttonAction?()
    }

    private func configure() {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonActionWrap), for: .touchUpInside)
        let height = self.frame.height
        let buttonHeight = height - 10
        button.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.width - (buttonHeight + 10), y: 5, width: buttonHeight, height: buttonHeight)
        button.setImage(buttonImage, for: .normal)
        self.button = button
        self.addSubview(button)
        bringSubview(toFront: button)
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Move `configure()` from `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` to `awakeFromNib()`

Comment: @beyowulf That did it. Go ahead and answer the question so I can mark it as accepted! If you don't mind, could you provide a short explanation as to why? In particular why everything but the image seemed to work fine? Thanks mate! :)